# Control input to itemprocessor in Spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch with reader/processor/writer. which works perfectly fine. The new requirement is the processor should process only 1 or 2 message and sleep for 1 or 2 sec depending on the load in the server (My item-processor calls 3rd party API to send some data, the 3rd party calls should not be continuous).

I have implemented chunk listener, but i m not able to identify how to read the message/item-process call, 
chunklistener "readcount" returns the number of message processed in incremental.

```
paramChunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getReadCount() //chunkcontext
```

One option that i m thinking of is to divide the chunkcount/2 and based on the return(if return is 0 - sleep for 1 sec). then

```
thread.sleep(1000) //
```

Is there any other better way to perform this? the above process is a dirty job.

Comment: Please define 'load in the server'.

Comment: @NghiaDo I have updated the details in my question

Comment: Could you please define "3rd party calls should not be continuous"?